# Using a cell's number to insert that many rows (with that row's data)

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in excel that looks like this

---

{name} {price} {quantity}

joe //  4.99 // 1

lisa // 2.99 // 3

jose // 6.99 // 1

---

Would it be hard to make a macro that will take the quantity value ("lisa // 3.99 // **3**") and add that many rows below it's current location. It would know which rows to copy, and how many rows to insert based on on the quantity column.

Thanks for reading, and feedback is helpful.

Comment: So you just want to insert X number of rows defined by the QTY?

Comment: yes, but I would also like that row (lisa // 2.9 // 3) to have its contents copied into those new rows. so the final result would have 1 joe, 3 lisa, and 1 jose (with their pricing data consistent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want, it polls through from the bottom up, if it encounters a number in C and it is > 1 then it will insert the number of rows equal to column C number - 1 then copy the data from the host row.

This will give you  4 equal rows where there is a 4 in column C, I think that is what you were after yes? If you want to ADD the number of rows equal to column C (So a value of 4 would add 4 NEW rows making the total count for that entry become 5) then let me know, it will be simple enough to change this

```
Sub InsertRowsByQTY()
Dim X As Long
For X = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Range("C" & X).text) Then
        If Range("C" & X).Value > 1 Then
            Rows(X + 1).Resize(Range("C" & X).Value - 1, Columns.Count).Insert
            Range("A" & X + 1).Resize(Range("C" & X).Value - 1, Cells(X, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column).Value = Range("A" & X).Resize(1, Cells(X, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column).Value
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method :

```
Sub insert()
Dim lastrow As Integer, frow As Integer

lastrow = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
frow = 0

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 3) > 1 Then
        frow = frow + Cells(i, 3)
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To lastrow + frow
    If Cells(i, 3) <> 1 Then
        nr = Cells(i, 3)
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + nr).Select
        Selection.insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rows(i & ":" & i + nr).Select
        Selection.FillDown
    i = i + nr
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```